# TFS automated build + nuget package restore + shared projects in different solutions

Tags: nuget

I have a solution that contains shared projects with nuget package restore.
I have a second solution that references projects from the first solution.

I am trying to set up TFS to build the second solution, but it doesn't find references for the projects in shared solution because the packages folder for the first solution is in a different location than that of the second solution.  I've included the first solution in the build, but now the build configuration doesn't exist in that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First of all, it sounds as if the shared projects could be packaged themselves and as such be shared across these two solutions.*

However, if you really don't want to do that, you might try the use the following NuGet commandline parameters and tweak the nuget.targets file in such way that they both point to the same package install directory. (note: you'll have to manually update the project references as well to point to the new packages location)

> nuget.exe install **-o "d:\some\dir"**

You can simply modify the  element in the nuget.targets file, or add this element in the csproj file's PropertyGroup with your own custom value.

> <PropertyGroup>
>
> <PackageOutputDir>d:\some\dir</PackageOutputDir>
>
> </PropertyGroup>

One last remark: the output location path has to be the same on the client development machine as on the TFS build agents or it won't work.

Comment: can the directory be a relative path?

Comment: That should work. If you want relative to the solution directory, you can use the $(SolutionDir) MSBuild variable and navigate from there. (e.g. $(SolutionDir)\..\..\GlobalPackages\)